# Hibernate with mysql overwrites pk

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Well, I'm using Hibernate for the first time and, unexpectedly, it works. Except for one thing: an insert with a pk already inserted overwrite the record instaed of preventing it.

That's my simple code:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/mainPage")
    public String viewMainPage(){
        return "mainPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public String viewInserisciUtente(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("nuovoUtente", new Utente());
        return "nuovo-utente";
    }

    @PostMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public String memorizzaUtente(@ModelAttribute Utente utente){
        userRepository.save(utente);
        return "output";
    }
}

@Entity
public class Utente {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String citta=null;
    private String genere=null;
    private String data_nascita=null;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCitta() {
        return citta;
    }

    public void setCitta(String citta) {
        this.citta = citta;
    }

    public String getGenere() {
        return genere;
    }

    public void setGenere(String genere) {
        this.genere = genere;
    }

    public String getData_nascita() {
        return data_nascita;
    }

    public void setData_nascita(String data_nascita) {
        this.data_nascita = data_nascita;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I've added the entity class to help you understanding my problem. Hoping that this will help.

Thanks you all

Comment: what's the save method in UserRepository does ?

Comment: userRepository is a CRUDRepository interface. It's an his method. That's the code:
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Utente, Integer> {
}

Comment: @Pikappa can you show the Entity class

Comment: Sure, that's it:

Comment: I've just edited my post

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) documentation, then we don't have update method, but we only have save method, which is used to add or update existing records.

In your case, you might have updated an entity (except its Id field) and tried saving the entity. So, CrudRepository will update the existing value for given Id, since it is already present.

Comment: And so what should I use instaed?

Comment: @Pikappa If you wanted to add new row to table. Then, change the Id value and it will add new row.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I would to completely prevents from overwrites. Like an error if I insert an Id already inserted (like what happends with a simple insert on workbench)

Comment: @Pikappa Then, why don't you use findById first and then see, if it is already present ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ID generation strategy to `id` field.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```